# Is there an "Incognito mode" for windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, privacy

I want to use my windows 7 without leaving any traces, like chrome incognito browsing or IE Inprivate browsing but for the whole system, and I don't want to use windows then clean traces using CCleaner or whatever.
Is there any software that allows me to do it (by creating a private session for example) ?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/665578/software-for-windows-similar-to-private-browsing-mode-of-browser

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/en-uk/products/deep-freeze/) , it resets your system to a pre-defined config every-time you reboot.

Comment: Thanks, I already know deep freeze, but i'm looking for a software which doesn't need a computer reboot, which just turns your current session to a private one.

Answer (score 1):

[Suggestions for setting up a kiosk mode in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152113/suggestions-for-setting-up-a-kiosk-mode-in-windows-7) (Stackoverflow thread)

OP solved the problem by running a batch script at shutdown, which removes, wipes, then recreates the user profile. This might not be exactly what you need, but it might be something to work with. Maybe you can schedule the script to run after every logoff.

Answer (score 0):

If you use VMware to recreate a virtual machine at each startup, it could work. However, it would be somewhat clunky unless you can create a backup .vhd that you could just copy and paste each time.